# Power BI - DAX question - How can I show only one result that meet the criteria from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, powerbi, logic, dax, candidate

I am working on this criteria where I have 6 columns called candidate id, qualification, country, gender, subject, grade. Now I want one candidate each of grade in (a,b,c,d,e,f) from country as India and one candidate each of grade in (a,b,c,d,e,f) from country as any other country except India. Additionally another criteria in this is one candidate each of subject in (maths, english, hindi) & grade in (1,2,3). I am trying to solve it through DAX.

I tried doing in SQL using row indexing but I am not able to do in Dax.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. However, are you looking for a SQL solution or not? (If you are, show us your current attempt. And add a tag for the dbms used.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.